# How to schedule a timer with initial delay?

Tags: java, swift, timer

In java, we can create a periodic executor with an initial delay that is the time to delay first execution. Here is an example:

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Fetcher(), 2, 10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

class Fetcher implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
              ...
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

For example, this runnable works after two minutes of the starting schedule. Then it works periodically for every ten minutes.

In Swift, we can schedule a timer like below:

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 120, target: self, selector: #selector(fetch(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

@objc fileprivate func fetch(_ timer: Timer!) {
    ...
}
```

But, how can we set an initial delay for a swift timer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `Timer` with parameter `fireAt` in initializer. As `fireAt` pass `Date` when you want to fire your timer

```
let initialDelayInSeconds = 5
let now = Date()
let date = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: now), minute: Calendar.current.component(.minute, from: now), second: Calendar.current.component(.second, from: now) + initialDelayInSeconds, of: now)!

let timer = Timer(fireAt: date, interval: 120, target: self, selector: #selector(fetch(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: .common) // don't forget to add `timer` to `RunLoop`
```

Comment: Ok, I missed that part. It is working now. I think this is the best solution. Thanks Robert!

Answer (score 1):

Using a `dispatch_after` block is in most cases better than using `sleep(time)` as the thread on which the sleep is performed is blocked from doing other work. when using `dispatch_after` the thread which is worked on does not get blocked so it can do other work in the meantime.
If you are working on the main thread of your application, using sleep(time) is bad for the user experience of your app as the UI is unresponsive during that time.

Dispatch after schedules the execution of a block of code instead of freezing the thread:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(4), execute: {

        // Put your code which should be executed with a delay here

    })
```

Comment: Same problem. It just postpones the creation. After 4 minutes, my fetcher function is not called.

Comment: In a dispatch, you have to mention after how many seconds your timer will start and a timer will take time to get executed fetch function.

Answer (score 0):

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 120, execute: {
       Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval:600, target: self, selector: #selector(fetch(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
})

@objc fileprivate func fetch(_ timer: Timer!) {

}
```

Comment: this does not work. After 120 seconds, the fetch function won't execute. It just postpones the creation.

Comment: It is working for perfectly. You might be doing something wrong.

Comment: import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

class Abc {
    
    init() {
        print("init")
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5, execute: {
            print("main")
            Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval:10, target: self, selector: #selector(self.fetch), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            print("after timer")
        })
    }
    
    @objc func fetch() {
        print("fetch")
    }
}

let a = Abc()

Comment: @Ahmet This should work.  You are passing `fetcher` to `Timer` but you have a different method in question i.e, `fetch`.

Comment: Ok. it has just been fixed. But this does not work. In my case, times should be: 2, 12, 22, 32.  but in this case : 12, 22, 32 ...

Comment: How this does not work when you asked `How to create a timer with initial delay?`?

Comment: The initial delay means like java. The selector function should work after initial delay then it works periodically.

Comment: In this case, the selector function is not called after the initial delay.

Comment: Now the question is how you recorded these numbers `2, 12, 22, 32`?  What if you are doing it wrongly? I would suggest go through this once [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Kamran please read the whole question, not just the title. Maybe, the title is not so good, sorry for that, but the question is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use `Timer` as below,

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2, repeats: false) { _ in
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2, target: self, selector: #selector(self.fetch(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

Or `DispatchQueue` as this,

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2, target: self, selector: #selector(self.fetch(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

Comment: they just postpone the creation. After 2 minutes, my fetcher function is not called.

Comment: Who knows what is `fetcher`?

Comment: Creation of what? Remember your fetch method will be called after `initialTime + timerInterval` i.e, (2+2) in above case so you have to wait for that amount of time.

Comment: in swift there is no fetcher. just there is one function. fetch()